# After upgrading Alfresco from 5.2 to 7.2 getting failed to initialize keystore error. Our old repository is in Alfresco 5.2

Tags: migration, alfresco

The tomcat log showing the following error when we try to access the repositry. Previously it was hosted in Windows server and new one is in Ubuntu 22.04. When accessing we get the following error.

[image]

Checking catalina.out it shows the failed to initialize keystore error.

[image]

tried to replace the new key store and the files in it with the old ones. Still same error is coming